# Ffmpeg - transform mulaw 8000khz audio buffer data into valid bytes format

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to read a bytes variable using ffmpeg, but the audio stream I listen to, sends me buffer data in **mulaw encoded buffer** like this:

https://github.com/boblp/mulaw_buffer_data/blob/main/buffer_data

I'm having trouble running the **ffmpeg_read** function from the transformers library found [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/pipelines/audio_utils.py#L10):

```
def ffmpeg_read(bpayload: bytes, sampling_rate: int) -> np.array:
"""
Helper function to read an audio file through ffmpeg.
"""
ar = f"{sampling_rate}"
ac = "1"
format_for_conversion = "f32le"
ffmpeg_command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    "pipe:0",
    "-ac",
    ac,
    "-ar",
    ar,
    "-f",
    format_for_conversion,
    "-hide_banner",
    "-loglevel",
    "quiet",
    "pipe:1",
]

try:
    with subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as ffmpeg_process:
        output_stream = ffmpeg_process.communicate(bpayload)
except FileNotFoundError as error:
    raise ValueError("ffmpeg was not found but is required to load audio files from filename") from error
out_bytes = output_stream[0]
audio = np.frombuffer(out_bytes, np.float32)
if audio.shape[0] == 0:
    raise ValueError(
        "Soundfile is either not in the correct format or is malformed. Ensure that the soundfile has "
        "a valid audio file extension (e.g. wav, flac or mp3) and is not corrupted. If reading from a remote "
        "URL, ensure that the URL is the full address to **download** the audio file."
    )
return audio
```

But everytime I get:

```
raise ValueError(
    "Soundfile is either not in the correct format or is malformed. Ensure that the soundfile has "
    "a valid audio file extension (e.g. wav, flac or mp3) and is not corrupted. If reading from a remote "
    "URL, ensure that the URL is the full address to **download** the audio file."
)
```

If I grab any wav file I can do something like this:

```
import wave

with open('./emma.wav', 'rb') as fd:
    contents = fd.read()
    print(contents)
```

And running it through the function does work!

So my question would be:

How can I transform my **mulaw encoded buffer** data into a valid bytes format that works with `ffmpeg_read()`?

**EDIT: I've found a way using pywav (https://pypi.org/project/pywav/)**

```
# 1 stands for mono channel, 8000 sample rate, 8 bit, 7 stands 
for MULAW encoding
wave_write = pywav.WavWrite("filename.wav", 1, 8000, 8, 7)
wave_write.write(mu_encoded_data)

wave_write.close()
```

This is the result: https://github.com/boblp/mulaw_buffer_data/blob/main/filename.wav

the background noise is acceptable.

However, I want to use a FFMPEG instead to avoid creating a tmp file.

Comment: Where did your data stream come from?  ffmpeg expects to read complete audio files, not isolated individual audio buffers.

Comment: From an audio stream, monitoring a phone call

Comment: The you may need to use a mulaw library, or some audio processing library that supports mulaw.  ffmpeg wasn't designed for this.

Comment: Seems like mulaw IS supported: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types

Comment: Well, have you tried `-f mulaw` on your ffmpeg command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import io

def ffmpeg_read_mulaw(bpayload: bytes, sampling_rate: int) -> np.array:
    ar = f"{sampling_rate}"
    ac = "1"
    format_for_conversion = "f32le"
    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-f",
        "mulaw",
        "-ar",
        ar,
        "-ac",
        ac,
        "-i",
        "pipe:0",
        "-b:a",#change the bitrate
        "256k", #change the bitrate to 256k
        "-f",
        format_for_conversion,
        "-hide_banner",
        "-loglevel",
        "quiet",
        "pipe:1",
    ]

    try:
        with subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as ffmpeg_process:
            output_stream = ffmpeg_process.communicate(bpayload)
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        raise ValueError("ffmpeg was not found but is required to load audio files from filename") from error

    out_bytes = output_stream[0]
    audio = np.frombuffer(out_bytes, np.float32)

    if audio.shape[0] == 0:
        raise ValueError("Failed to decode mu-law encoded data with FFMPEG.")

    return audio

# Example usage:
# mu_encoded_data is your mu-law encoded buffer data
mu_encoded_data = b"\x7F\xFF\x80\x01\x7F\xFF"
sampling_rate = 8000
decoded_audio = ffmpeg_read_mulaw(mu_encoded_data, sampling_rate)
print(decoded_audio)
```

Comment: NICE, Is there a way to fix the quality?

Comment: You can try to change the bitrate. See the updated code. Also you can try using different audio codecs (I am not sure how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

For my telecom programs I use [G.711 codec](https://pypi.org/project/g711/) to work with 8 kHz audio.

It would be something like:

```py
from g711 import decode_ulaw

samples = decode_ulaw(mu_encoded_data) # numpy array of float32
```